# Erro na instalação do MySql

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Após tentar instalar o pacote LAMP no Ubuntu 16.04, estou recebendo o erro:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Já reinstalei 2x todo o MySql;

`apt remove mysql*` e `apt- purge mysql*`.

Tentei instalar o MySql 5.6 e 5.7 e ambos retornam o mesmo erro.

Versão do PHP instalada:

> PHP 7.0.11-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 (cli) ( NTS )
>   Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
>   Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
>       with Zend OPcache v7.0.11-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies

Apache:

> PHP 7.0.11-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 (cli) ( NTS )
>   Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
>   Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
>       with Zend OPcache v7.0.11-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies

Comment: Qual comando você usou pra instalar o mysql ?

Comment: @Douglas, tentei com `apt-get install mysql-server` (isso instala o 5.7), e tambem tentei adicionar o ppa da versão 5.6.

Comment: Certo, e como você está tentando acessar o mysql no qual retorna este erro ?

Comment: `mysql -u root -p`

Comment: Certo, acredito que possa te ajudar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990708/error-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run-mysqld-mysq

Comment: @Douglas, eu já havia visto este tópico e como voce pode ver ele é relacionado a ausência de um arquivo, o que não é meu caso...

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver reiniciando o pc e instalando

`sudo apt-get install mysql-client-core-5.7`

e em seguida o

`sudo apt-get install mysql-server`